# How to calculate 2 Unix timeSpan difference. e.g. int endTime=1213036458; int startTime= 1211018446;

Tags: java, unix-timestamp

How do we calculate the Unix timeSpan in Java?

```
int endTime=1213036458;
int startTime= 1211018446;
```

The result should be in hours.

Answer (score 2):

[Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is usually (from the Wikipedia link) *defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970*. That particular [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) is shared by Java, but Java uses milliseconds instead of seconds.

If you're using Java 8+ you could use a `Duration` like

```
int endTime = 1213036458;
int startTime = 1211018446;
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds(endTime - startTime);
System.out.println(d);
```

Which gives me (560 hours, 33 minutes and 32 seconds)

```
PT560H33M32S
```

If you're using an older version of Java you could always implement it with something like

```
int seconds = endTime - startTime;
int hours = seconds / 3600;
seconds -= hours * 3600;
int minutes = seconds / 60;
seconds -= minutes * 60;
System.out.printf("%d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds%n", hours,
    minutes, seconds);
```

And I get the expected

```
560 hours, 33 minutes and 32 seconds
```